# php combine if empty statment syntax

Tags: php, drupal

How can I combine the two if statements below, but I would like the page to display the breadcrumbs if one OR the other fields are present.

```
<?php if (!empty($secondaryslider)): ?>
<?php if (!empty($node->field_upload_banner[0]['view'])) {?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `||` or `OR`

```
if (!empty($secondaryslider) || !empty($node->field_upload_banner[0]['view']))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `||`:

```
<?php if ( !empty($secondaryslider) || !empty($node->field_upload_banner[0]['view']) ): ?>
```

Comment: Edited after you specified you wanted one OR the other

Answer (score 0):

very straight forward

```
<?php if (!empty($secondaryslider) && !empty($node->field_upload_banner[0]['view'])): ?>
```